# How to fix the boot loader with an installation disk at hand

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, updates

I recently messed up my Master Boot Record and my system is not booting. I was dual booting Windows and Ubuntu. Both of them are not loading now. I don't care if I lose my windows, but I want my Ubuntu back!!

How to get it (I have a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 LTS disk with me). I went through the install wizard but feared that I may loose my existing installation/setup. Thats why I came here to check what is the ideal procedure to only update the Boot record instead of a full installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in detail in the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20from%20LiveCD).

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I am trying the steps now.. Will post an update soon..

Comment: AMAZINGGGG!!!!!! THANKS A BILLION!!!!!! I feared that I would lose my entire work!! You saved me many hours and days of work!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an alternate CD you can use "Rescue a broken System" when this has loaded you can see a menu entry to re-install the grub menu.